# insert check function inside submit function to check if there missing inputs before send data to the backend server in Vue JS

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, validation

I want to add function to prevent submit button from submit data to server if there are empty inputs.
I wrote a **checkform** function to check if all inputs not empty but i do not how can i insert this function inside **createReport** function

```
checkForm: function (e) {
     if (this.tops && this.bottoms && this.build && this.wallNumber &&this.authors ) {
       return true;
     } else {
return false
}
};
```

My HTML

```
<v-btn  width="100%" class="primary" :loading="isbuildGenerating" @submit="createReport(true)">Generate</v-btn>
```

java script

```
         createReport: function (isCraft=true) {
          this.$refs.form.validate()
          this.$emit('buildGenerated', null)
          this.isbuildGenerated = true
          this.isbuildGenerated = false    
          let jsonData = {
            build:this.build, 
            wallNumber:this.wallNumber,
            time:this.time,
            bottoms:this.bottoms
            tops:this.tops
            authors:this.authors
 }
            this.$axios.post(this.$backendUrl + '/buildoperations', jsonData)
            .then(response => {
            this.pdfData = { data: response.data }
            this.$emit('pdfGenerated', this.pdfData)
            this.isbuildGenerated = true
            this.isbuildGenerating = false
          })
}
```

Comment: Perhaps the first thing to do is to change `@submit="createReport(true)"` to `@submit.prevent="createReport(true)"` to prevent default submission behavior, and to delay it until you can verify that the form's data is sufficient.

Comment: thanks alot, i will update it, but how can I insert check form function to CreateReport to validate inputs
@HovercraftFullOfEels

Comment: you can't simply call in createReport and eval his return before do post call to server?

Comment: `if(!this.checkForm()) return;` ?

Comment: thanks alot, would you please more explanation about where can i insert this code exactly 
@SouXin

Comment: you can add this at any place. You can add that before building the `jsonData` object.